# Draw Arrows outside of content-area of TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a rather standard tikz plot. To clarify that low values on the y axis are actually faster/better I want to draw an additional arrow outside of the actually plotting area as shown in the attachment.
I found various ways of drawing using `\draw` but they all operate only within the content area of the plot - how can I draw outside of this area?

Here is a MWE of how I create my plot at the moment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
         \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={X}, 
        ylabel=time,
        xmin=0.8,
        xmax=1.0,
        ymin=1,     
        ymax=200,   
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
    ]      

\addplot+[
            black,
            mark options={fill= black},
            only marks,
            mark size=2,
            mark=square*,
        ] 
        coordinates {
            (0.805, 10)
            (0.85, 20)

        };



    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using pgfplots or is this drawn in plain tikz? Please provide a minimum working example with some data to create the plot.

Comment: Standard TikZ plot, or standard `pgfplots` plot? (I.e. an `axis` environment.) If the latter, add `clip=false` to the `axis` options, or draw the arrow outside the `axis` environment. For that method, it might be useful to add e.g. `name=myaxis` to the `axis` options, so you can access the anchors like `myaxis.outer north west`.

Comment: I added a MWE of how I create the plot at the moment

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Also `clip mode=individual` is very handy (I have it on by default in my templates). This will clip graphs but not the added things (`node`s, `path`s etc.)

Comment: @Rmano Yes, I'm aware of that, but neglected to mention it in my comment..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We `name` the `axis`, so as to be able to access it outside the `axis` environment.

Then, we draw a line between some key points of it.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75, >=stealth']
  \pgfplotsset{grid style={dashed,gray}}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      name=myGraph,
      xlabel={X}, 
      ylabel=time,
      xmin=0.8,
      xmax=1.0,
      ymin=1,     
      ymax=200,   
      xmajorgrids=true,
      ymajorgrids=true,
    ]      

    \addplot+
    [
      black,
      mark options={fill= black},
      only marks,
      mark size=2,
      mark=square*,
    ] 
    coordinates 
    {
      (0.805, 10)
      (0.85, 20)
    };
  \end{axis}

  \def\myShift{-2cm}
  \draw [red, very thick, ->] ([xshift=\myShift]myGraph.north west) -- ([xshift=\myShift]myGraph.south west) node [midway, rotate=90, fill=white, yshift=2pt] {faster} ;
  %\draw [red, very thick, ->] (myGraph.left of north west) -- (myGraph.left of south west) node [midway, rotate=90, fill=white, yshift=2pt] {faster} ; % an alternative way
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cheers,

Comment: I prefer your commented alternative solution, because this has the advantage that one doesn't have to adjust a "one time set" `xshift` in case the (horizontal) size of an `x label` or the size of the `yticklabels` changes.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice. Should I edit the answer ?

Comment: That's up to you. It is your answer. Both solutions are valid and could be better depending on the situation. (Every solution has its pros and cons.) I (personally) just think that the commented answer is the one that more often would be "easier" compared to the non-commented one ;)

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: Changed `rel axis cs` to `axis description cs` as suggested in the comments.

You can use the `axis description cs` coordinate system for stuff like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            grid style = {dashed, gray},
            xlabel={X}, 
            ylabel=time,
            xmin=0.8,
            xmax=1.0,
            ymin=1,     
            ymax=200,   
            xmajorgrids=true,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            clip = false % <--- Important
        ]      
        \addplot+
        [
            black,
            mark options={fill= black},
            only marks,
            mark size=2,
            mark=square*,
        ] 
        coordinates { (0.805, 10) (0.85, 20) };
        % add annotation here:
        \draw[red, ->] ([xshift = -2cm] axis description cs:0, 1) -- node[left] { Faster } ([xshift = -2cm] axis description cs:0, 0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of answer]
The point `(axis description cs:0, 1)` is the upper left point, `(axis description cs:0, 0)` is the lower left point. Both points are shifted by `2cm` (arbitrary, choose for your taste). Note that you have to turn off clipping in the `axis` environment, otherwise all stuff drawn outside the axis will be not visible.

I always have the feeling, things like this can be solved better. In my opinion, you should always choose your units and things you want to show to reflect your point. In this case, maybe it would be possible to use the inverse of time (perhaps frequency) to plot the data? I don't know what you are showing, but keep in mind that it's better (in my opinion) to solve things not by clever technical/texnical tricks (adding a custom annotation) than by using the right visualization method.

Comment: Good point about frequency vs. (response ?) time. One could also add a title stating "lower time is faster".

Comment: I would prefer to use `axis description cs` instead of `rel axis cs`, because it is independent of axis reversals or skewed axes. To show what I mean, add `x dir=reverse,` to the `axis` options and compare both results ...

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was always wondering about the difference of the two.

Comment: You should also change the description below the figure ...