# How to draw text along the path defined by a function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, decorations

I'm still dabbling in the use of pgfplots but I'm trying to draw arrows on this plot to show an inverse correlation between the variation in the arc length along the curve and the changes in x.

Given that a picture is worth a thousand words, I'll show you my code, the corresponding output and an image of the desired output, so that you can compare and notice the changes I'd like to get.

Also, you might notice my code is based on the information I collected from these posts: [Draw Arrows outside of content-area of TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350692/draw-arrows-outside-of-content-area-of-tikz), [Tikzpicture - Arrow next to/under plot label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051150/tikzpicture-arrow-next-to-under-plot-label) and [Pgfplots: plot text along function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237456/pgfplots-plot-text-along-function). However, I just haven't been able to make it work together.

I've been struggling with this all night long, so sny help is highly appreciated. In fact, if you could add some explanations on how and why your solution works, so that I can learn from it and do better in the future I'd be forever in debt with you :')

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.text,arrows.meta,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
name=MyAxis,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xmin=0,
xmax=25,
ymin=0,
ymax=21,
axis y line=center, 
axis x line=center,
ytick=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
]
\addplot[black,domain=0:21,samples=200,very thick]{(-5/4)*21^(3/5)*x^(2/5)+5*x^(8/5)/(16*21^(3/5))+315/16};
\addplot[draw=none,
          postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
              text={Increasing values of s},raise=2ex,
              text align=center,
              text effects/.cd, 
              text along path,
              every character/.style={fill=white,text=blue, yshift=-0.5ex}
              }},
              domain=0:21,
    ] {(-5/4)*21^(3/5)*x^(2/5)+5*x^(8/5)/(16*21^(3/5))+350/16};
\addplot+[mark=none,blue,
      domain=2:15,latex-,samples=150
    ] {-(5/4)*21^(3/5)*(x-1.5)^(2/5)+5*(x-1.5)^(8/5)/(16*21^(3/5))+(350/16)};
\end{axis}
\def\myShift{-1cm}
  \draw [-latex] ([yshift=-4ex]MyAxis.outer south west) --node[midway, fill=white, yshift=1pt]{Increasing values of $x$} ([yshift=-4ex]MyAxis.outer south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Path travelled by dog after $t$ seconds}
\label{ref:my7graph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

This is what I'd like to get:
[image]

Notice the changes:

- Shorter horizontal arrow below the x axis.
- Zero at the origin.
- White background for the text along the curved arrow.
- *If possible, I'd like to type the "s" in mathmode along the curved arrow.*

## **Edit**

These days I read part of the [TikZ manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf), as well as [this](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) and [this](https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) manual, and found a rudimentary solution. Hopefully someone might come up with a better idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.text,arrows.meta,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
name=MyAxis,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xmin=0,
xmax=25,
ymin=0,
ymax=21,
axis y line=center, 
axis x line=center,
ytick=\empty,
xtick=\empty,
legend entries={$y(x)$},
legend pos=north east]
\addlegendimage{no marks,dashed,very thick,gray}
]
\addplot[gray,dashed,domain=0:21,samples=200,very thick]{(-5/4)*21^(3/5)*x^(2/5)+5*x^(8/5)/(16*21^(3/5))+315/16};
\addplot[draw=none,
          postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
              text={Increasing values of s},raise=-0.5ex,
              text align=center,
              text effects/.cd, 
              text along path,
              every character/.style={text=blue}
              }},
              domain=0:17.5,
    ] {(-5/4)*21^(3/5)* (x-1.31684)^(2/5)+(5*(x-1.31684)^(8/5))/(16*21^(3/5))+(315/16)+1.15223};
\addplot[stealth-,blue,very thick,samples=200,domain=2:3]{(-5/4)*21^(3/5)* (x-1.31684)^(2/5)+(5*(x-1.31684)^(8/5))/(16*21^(3/5))+(315/16)+1.15223};
\addplot[blue,very thick,samples=200,domain=11.75:14]{(-5/4)*21^(3/5)* (x-1.31684)^(2/5)+(5*(x-1.31684)^(8/5))/(16*21^(3/5))+(315/16)+1.15223};
\end{axis}
\draw (0,0) node [below left] {$0$};
\draw [anchor=base, very thick] (4ex,-3ex)--(10ex,-3ex) node [right] {Increasing values of $x$} [-stealth, xshift=28ex](6ex,-3ex)--(12ex,-3ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Inverse correlation between $s$ and $x$}
\label{ref:fig2}
\end{figure}
```

This is the output:
[image]

As you might see, I found a way to add a label for the origin and shorten the arrows, but haven't been able to type the blue 's' in `mathmode`. Again, any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: The yshift accounts for the lopsidedness.  Try preaction instead.

Comment: [Did you check this answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511457/how-to-typeset-text-along-the-curve-of-a-mathematical-function-with-tikz)

Comment: Do you need the construction in this case only?  Or do you plan to use it in more complicated cases?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm sorry, I don't quite know how to do that. Could you give me more details or recommend me some documentation to learn, please?

Comment: @SebGlav I'd seen it, but I hadn't read it carefully. I found [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511567/how-to-typeset-maths-above-the-curve-of-a-function-with-tikz-with-the-curve-mas) related to it that mentions the package <contour> which seems to be exactly what I need, thanks! However, I'm struggling to implement it in this case and I don't understand how the user who answered there used it in his code... I'm also new to this forum, should I reply there or add a reference here?

Comment: Replies on this site are only for answers. If you want to ask your question in another way, you would ask another one (and maybe delete this one).

Comment: @DanielN I was planning to use something similar for another diagram, so a general solution would be better.

Comment: I've learned a little better how to use `text effects along path` and I think I've found how to set the *s* in math mode (for the text inside the arrow).  I updated my answer along this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Updated answer*

I propose a construction of the graph based on `plot` rather than `addplot` from `pgfplots`.

- The function must be written differently, using `pow(x, y)` for *x* at the power *y*.
- I put the text above the arrow on the left and in the arrow on the right (the update).
  The decorations are slightly different: the first is based on `text along path` and the second on `text effects along path` (as in your work).  The math mode for *s* (in fact `\itshape`) is achieved through the option `character <number>`.
- There is a second argument for both decorations; for the former, the second argument sets the color; for the latter, it sets the character which appears in italic.
- (Side remark) Looking only at the image, it is not clear what is meant by *s*.  You should say it at least in the figure's caption.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=.7cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  fancy text/.style 2 args={%
    postaction={
      decorate, decoration={%
        text along path,
        text={|\small|#1},
        text align=center,
        text color=#2,
        raise=.7ex,
      }
    }
  },
  over/.style 2 args={%
    postaction={%
      decorate, decoration={%
        text effects along path,
        text={#1},
        text align=center,
        text effects/.cd, 
        text along path,
        characters={fill=white, yshift=-.5ex},
        character #2/.style={font=\itshape}
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3, every node/.style={scale=.8}]
  % axes
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (22, 0) node[below=1ex] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 21) node[left=1ex] {$y$};
  \path (0, 0) node[below left] {$O$};

  % curve
  \draw[blue!70!black, very thick, variable=\t, domain=0:21, samples=200]
  plot (\t, {
    (-5/4)*pow(21, 3/5)*pow(\t, 2/5)
    +5/16*pow(\t, 8/5)/pow(21, 3/5)
    +315/16
  });

  % arrows for s and x
  \draw[blue, thin, variable=\t, domain=2:14, samples=200,
  arrows={Latex-},
  fancy text={increasing values of |\scriptsize|{$s$}}{blue}]
  plot (\t, {
    (-5/4)*pow(21, 3/5)*pow(\t -1.3, 2/5)
    +5/16*pow(\t -1.3, 8/5)/pow(21, 3/5)
    +315/16 +1.15
  });

  \draw[blue, thin, arrows={-Latex},
  fancy text={increasing values of |\scriptsize|{$x$}}{blue}]
  (2, -3) -- ++(13, 0);

  % label
  \draw[blue!70!black, very thick] (17.5, 18) -- ++(3, 0)
  node[right] {$y(x)$};
  \draw[very thin] (17, 17) rectangle ++(6.25, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3, every node/.style={scale=.8}]
  % axes
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (22, 0) node[below=1ex] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 21) node[left=1ex] {$y$};
  \path (0, 0) node[below left] {$O$};

  % curve
  \draw[blue!70!black, very thick, variable=\t, domain=0:21, samples=100]
  plot (\t, {
    (-5/4)*pow(21, 3/5)*pow(\t, 2/5)
    +5/16*pow(\t, 8/5)/pow(21, 3/5)
    +315/16
  });

  % arrows for s and x
  \draw[blue, thin, variable=\t, domain=2:14, samples=100,
  arrows={Latex-},
  over={~increasing values of s~}{23}]
  plot (\t, {
    (-5/4)*pow(21, 3/5)*pow(\t -1.3, 2/5)
    +5/16*pow(\t -1.3, 8/5)/pow(21, 3/5)
    +315/16 +1.15
  });

  \draw[blue, thin, arrows={-Latex},
  over={~increasing values of x~}{23}]
  (1, -3) -- ++(15, 0);

  % label
  \draw[blue!70!black, very thick] (17.5, 18) -- ++(3, 0)
  node[right] {$y(x)$};
  \draw[very thin] (17, 17) rectangle ++(6.25, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3, every node/.style={scale=.8}]
  % axes
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (22, 0) node[below=1ex] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 21) node[left=1ex] {$y$};
  \path (0, 0) node[below left] {$O$};

  % curve
  \draw[blue!70!black, very thick, variable=\t, domain=0:21, samples=100]
  plot (\t, {
    (-5/4)*pow(21, 3/5)*pow(\t, 2/5)
    +5/16*pow(\t, 8/5)/pow(21, 3/5)
    +315/16
  });

  % arrows for s and x
  \draw[blue, thin, variable=\t, domain=2:14, samples=100,
  arrows={Latex-},
  over={~increasing values of s~}{23}]
  plot (\t, {
    (-5/4)*pow(21, 3/5)*pow(\t -1.3, 2/5)
    +5/16*pow(\t -1.3, 8/5)/pow(21, 3/5)
    +315/16 +1.15
  });

  \draw[blue, thin, arrows={-Latex},
  over={~increasing values of x~}{23}]
  (1, -3) -- ++(15, 0);

  % label
  \draw[blue!70!black, very thick] (17.5, 18) -- ++(3, 0)
  node[right] {$y(x)$};
  \draw[very thin] (17, 17) rectangle ++(6.25, 2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```